# Does the JDK version being used to compile the code matter?

Tags: java, jvm

In a conversation with someone else, they claimed that the version of JDK being used to compile the code does not matter vs. the JVM version being used to run the compiled code.

That seems strange to me - are there never instances where the JDK version matters? Is functionality always only dependent on the JVM the code is running on, and not on how the code is being compiled?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19554706/2687324 talks about backwards compatibility. Is Java code also forwards compatible?

Comment: Are you talking about a situation where you *don't* use `-target` or `-source` when compiling?

Comment: I can't confirm - someone else is writing the code. Furthermore, even if they did use those tags, they wouldn't know what values to use since they never asked...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't necessarily run code compiled with a new JDK on an old JRE. Compiled classes contain a version number for the class file format; if this is newer than the runtime expects, it will refuse to load the class.

Most Java compilers support an option to target an older JRE, generating an older class file format than the compiler was built for. However, you can still run into trouble if you don't also compile against an older version of the Java runtime library. Your code might use new API that isn't in the older version of Java. The compiler, with its current version of the API, won't catch this even when you specify an older target.

For the standard `javac` compiler in OpenJDK, these options are `-target` and `-bootclasspath`. You might also want to set the `-source` option to catch usage of newer language features that require support the older class files don't provide.

Comment: So it does matter what JDK version is used to compile the code? I'm looking to minimize risk - does that mean it is best to use the same JDK version to compile the code as the JVM version to run the code (or at least the same major version)?

Comment: The `-target` option is well-supported and used frequently. I can't evaluate your risk though. If you are worried about a reactor meltdown, you should probably run your code on the JRE that was distributed with your JDK. But when facing less dire consequences, `-target` is an accepted practice.

Comment: I'm getting the compiled code from this person, and they stated that it doesn't matter what JDK version I'm using. I suspect they aren't using `-target` for the version of JVM I'm using, since they never asked.

Comment: What happens if they don't use `-target`?

Comment: Then you'll need to run it on a JRE that's no older than the compiler they used. If they used Java 8 and didn't set target, you'll need to run under Java 8. If they used 1.4, you should be able to run it on 1.4 or anything newer. You can check their class file version with `javap -v <fqn.ClassName>` Major version 52 -> Java 8; 51 -> Java 7, etc.

Comment: If something is compiled with JDK 1.4, does that mean all the known problems with Java 1.4 come with it even if I use a later version of JVM?

Comment: No. If a bug is in the runtime, rather than *your* code, upgrading to a newer JVM will eliminate the problem. So, in general, running your code, no matter how old it is, with the newest stable JVM, is going to give you the best performance, stability, etc. For example, updates to Java 7 are ending this month. If you want bug fixes, you'll *need* to run Java 8 (or pay Oracle for extended support). But you definitely don't need to re-compile any of your existing code with Java 8.

Comment: This is old but I'm curious what will happen if I use some third party libs already compiled with newer version 1.8, while my java project is targeting older version 1.6. My program will work on JRE 1.6? If not, what about 1.8?

Comment: @Jenix No, you won't be able to use version 8 class files on a version 6 JRE. However, you could use version 6 class files, or a mix of 6 and 8 class files on a version 8 JRE.

Comment: Thanks but one more question! Is there no way to make those libs work if I have no original source code to recompile with my project? (aside from decompiling them all by myself..) My customer wants the program to run on older JREs.. :(

Comment: @Jenix If they really are newer class files, there's no easy way around it. Hard ways around it would be comparing the class file structure to Java 6's, and seeing if you could simply change the version number or make other structural changes to the class file. Or you could use a decompiler, adapt the code to Java 6, and recompile.

Comment: I see.. Thank you!

Comment: on android you can use JDK 8 to build and compile a app and it will run on android 4.0(jre 6 or 7 i think)

Comment: just wondering how is this possible with android then ? if you guys are saying its not possible

Comment: @izzyMachado I’m not a mobile developer, but my understanding is that Android doesn’t run .class files. It runs .dex files, and how those are built depend on the Android tool chain you use, but I expect that most people these days compile directly from .java to .dex without an intermediate .class. If you include an existing library of .class files, again, the toolchain in use will determine what versions are compatible, but I’m guessing most chains support a wide range of class file versions from very old to Java 8 at least and maybe beyond. This would be a good new question.

Comment: wow didn't even think of that, makes sense they run .dex files! I wonder how I should word the new question ?